# Exception in thread Thread-4 - finding the reason or catch the exception

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm running this script on my server in order to send push notifications on new mail arrival. It works great but sometimes the script will crash with the error below. I don't know why it's crashing and I can't reproduce it on my own. When it fails it won't go into the except section. 
I've tried: `except self.abort:` `except M.abort:` `except M.error:`

1. Any idea why it's crashing?
2. Is it possible, for a short term solution,  to kill all the threads and restart the script from the `except` section?

.......

```
import socket, ssl, json, struct, re
import imaplib2, time
from threading import *

# enter gmail login details here
USER="YOUR.NAME@gmail.com"
PASSWORD="YOUR-GMAIL-PASSWORD"
# enter device token here
deviceToken = 'XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX '
deviceToken = deviceToken.replace(' ','').decode('hex')
currentBadgeNum = -1

def getUnseen():
    (resp, data) = M.status("INBOX", '(UNSEEN)')
    print data
    return int(re.findall("UNSEEN (\d)*\)", data[0])[0])    

def sendPushNotification(badgeNum):
    global currentBadgeNum, deviceToken
    if badgeNum != currentBadgeNum:
        currentBadgeNum = badgeNum
        thePayLoad = {
             'aps': {
        #          'alert':'Hello world!',
                  'sound':'',
                  'badge': badgeNum,
                  },
             'test_data': { 'foo': 'bar' },
             }
        theCertfile = 'certfile.pem'
        theHost = ('gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com', 2195)

        data = json.dumps(thePayLoad)
        theFormat = '!BH32sH%ds' % len(data)
        theNotification = struct.pack(theFormat, 0, 32, deviceToken, len(data), data)

        ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM), certfile=theCertfile)
        ssl_sock.connect(theHost)
        ssl_sock.write(theNotification)
        ssl_sock.close()
        print "Sent Push alert."

# This is the threading object that does all the waiting on 
# the event
class Idler(object):
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.idle)
        self.M = conn
        self.event = Event()

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        # This is a neat trick to make thread end. Took me a 
        # while to figure that one out!
        self.event.set()

    def join(self):
        self.thread.join()

    def idle(self):
        # Starting an unending loop here
        while True:
            # This is part of the trick to make the loop stop 
            # when the stop() command is given
            if self.event.isSet():
                return
            self.needsync = False
            # A callback method that gets called when a new 
            # email arrives. Very basic, but that's good.
            def callback(args):
                if not self.event.isSet():
                    self.needsync = True
                    self.event.set()
            # Do the actual idle call. This returns immediately, 
            # since it's asynchronous.
            self.M.idle(callback=callback)
            # This waits until the event is set. The event is 
            # set by the callback, when the server 'answers' 
            # the idle call and the callback function gets 
            # called.
            self.event.wait()
            # Because the function sets the needsync variable,
            # this helps escape the loop without doing 
            # anything if the stop() is called. Kinda neat 
            # solution.
            if self.needsync:
                self.event.clear()
                self.dosync()

    # The method that gets called when a new email arrives. 
    def dosync(self):
        print "Got an event!"
        numUnseen = getUnseen()
        sendPushNotification(numUnseen)

try:
    # Set the following two lines to your creds and server
    print 'starting'
    global M
    M = imaplib2.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
    M.login(USER, PASSWORD)
    # We need to get out of the AUTH state, so we just select 
    # the INBOX.
    #M.list()
    M.select('INBOX', readonly=True)
    numUnseen = getUnseen()
    getText()
    #print M.status("INBOX", '(UNSEEN)')
    # Start the Idler thread
    sendPushNotification(numUnseen)
    idler = Idler(M)
    idler.start()
    # Sleep forever, one minute at a time
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)

except self.abort:
    print 'we had a problem, dont worry! Ill fix it!'
    idler = Idler(M)
finally:
    # Clean up.
    idler.stop()
    idler.join()
    M.close()
    # This is important!
    M.logout()
```

.....................

.....................

```
  17:35.99 imap.gmail.com reader last 20 log messages:
  17:36.02 imap.gmail.com handler last 20 log messages:
Got an event!
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "serverx.py", line 229, in idle
    self.dosync()
  File "serverx.py", line 235, in dosync
    numUnseen = getUnseen()
  File "serverx.py", line 150, in getUnseen
    (resp, data) = M.status("INBOX", '(UNSEEN)')
  File "/home/myuser/lib/python2.7/imaplib2/imaplib2.py", line 1121, in status
    return self._simple_command(name, mailbox, names, **kw)
  File "/home/myuser/lib/python2.7/imaplib2/imaplib2.py", line 1607, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(self._command(name, *args), kw)
  File "/home/myuser/lib/python2.7/imaplib2/imaplib2.py", line 1305, in _command
    raise self.abort('connection closed')
abort: connection closed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try catching `imaplib2.IMAP4.abort`:

```
try:
    # ...
except imaplib2.IMAP4.abort:
    # Oh no! An error!
```

Comment: I will but how can I restart the script from inside the except?

Comment: @EXEC_BAD_ACCESS: You'll probably want to run the `try` in a loop. When/if it fails, you'll want to close the existing connection, (maybe) wait a little bit, then go into the `try` again and reconnect.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question (new to python) How do I run `try` again from inside the `except`?

Comment: @EXEC_BAD_ACCESS: If the whole `try`/`except` thing is in a loop and you just ignore the exception from the `except`, it'll just loop around again.

Comment: I don't need to add `pass` inside `except imaplib2.IMAP4.abort:` if I want the exception to be ignored?

Comment: @EXEC_BAD_ACCESS: `pass` doesn't actually *do* anything; `pass` really does only mean "do nothing". The reason for its existence is to make it so that if you have a block that you don't want to do anything in, you can use it explicitly, since you can't have a *truly* empty block (since that's likely unintentional, so will result in a syntax error). In short, whether it's `pass` in there or something else, it doesn't really matter; you just put `pass` there if there's nothing else you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do solve the same problem and I've succeeded.

You need to wrap the `self.M.idle(callback=callback)` with `try-except` and then re-raise it in the main thread. Then you handle the exception by re-running the code in the main thread to restart the connection.

You can find more details of the solution and possible reasons in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50163971/1544154

Complete solution is here: https://www.github.com/Elijas/email-notifier